# include a framework's header without explicitly including the framework's name?

Tags: xcode, frameworks, import, header, include

I have searched all around and it seems is not possible, but one never know.
I'm including a framework in a MacOSX application (Xcode). Everything works fine if I have

```
#include <MyFramework/MyHeader.h>
```

But this is not ideal for me, because it's a cross-platform project and other OS don't need the ´extra´ framework name in the includes.
If I add the Headers symlink path of the framework to

```
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS
```

I can use only

```
#include <MyHeader.h>
```

though this is not an ideal solution. So is it really impossible to have it another way? thank you!